# Find all subsets of length k in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, subset, powerset

Given a set `{1,2,3,4,5...n}` of n elements, we need to find all subsets of length k .

For example, if n = 4 and k = 2, the `output` would be `{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}`.

I am not even able to figure out how to start. We don't have to use the inbuilt library functions like next_permutation etc.

Need the algorithm and implementation in either C/C++ or Java.

Comment: Please see another thread with the same question and an alternative method to the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n/42190945#42190945 (can be converted from C# to Java readily)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Recursion is your friend for this task.

For each element - "guess" if it is in the current subset, and recursively invoke with the guess and a smaller superset you can select from. Doing so for both the "yes" and "no" guesses - will result in all possible subsets.

Restraining yourself to a certain length can be easily done in a stop clause.

Java code:

```
private static void getSubsets(List<Integer> superSet, int k, int idx, Set<Integer> current,List<Set<Integer>> solution) {
    //successful stop clause
    if (current.size() == k) {
        solution.add(new HashSet<>(current));
        return;
    }
    //unseccessful stop clause
    if (idx == superSet.size()) return;
    Integer x = superSet.get(idx);
    current.add(x);
    //"guess" x is in the subset
    getSubsets(superSet, k, idx+1, current, solution);
    current.remove(x);
    //"guess" x is not in the subset
    getSubsets(superSet, k, idx+1, current, solution);
}

public static List<Set<Integer>> getSubsets(List<Integer> superSet, int k) {
    List<Set<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<>();
    getSubsets(superSet, k, 0, new HashSet<Integer>(), res);
    return res;
}
```

Invoking with:

```
List<Integer> superSet = new ArrayList<>();
superSet.add(1);
superSet.add(2);
superSet.add(3);
superSet.add(4);
System.out.println(getSubsets(superSet,2));
```

Will yield:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Thanks, that does it. I also had this in mind. But I was looking for something efficient.

Comment: @sTEAK.: There are exponantial number of subsets, so efficient is not really an option I am afraid. Good Luck!

Comment: For given n and k (which is the problem at hand) there's a polynomial number of subsets, roughly O(n^k).

Comment: @AdarHefer No, it is exponential in k, which is input - not constant. So n^k is most definetly not polynomial.

Comment: @amit - What if we don't care about the order of the elements in the subsets? suppose we wanted to include also `[1, 2], [2, 1]`, what will we change?

Comment: @Nimrod This answer is aimed for "sets" (unordered). Basically, you will need to keep track of the elements you have used (to not allow multiple usages) - and in the "guess" step, you have more than "use" and "don't use" options, you need to iterate over all unused values.

Comment: @amit - another small question please - why did you choose implementing it with `Set`? the main idea of "set" is that it avoids duplications, right? but here your algorithm already handles it..

Comment: @Nimrod Though I don't rememver what I had in mind 4 years ago, I would have probably used set today as well because its more readable. Even though the algorithm takes care of not having duplicates, having the type `Set` makes it more readable and easier to understand.

Comment: Thoughts on making the return type of the getSubsets function Set<Set<Integer>> instead of List<Set<Integer>>? Another algorithm could solve this in a way that would result in a different ordering of the subsets but it would still solve the problem so maybe Set indicates this clearer?

Comment: What about the empty set?

Comment: @DavidG empty set is of length 0,  and this is trivially fulfilled in the stop clause after one invokation of `getSubsets()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a bit vector representation of the set, and use an algorithm similar to what std::next_permutation does on 0000.1111 (n-k zeroes, k ones). Each permutation corresponds to a subset of size k.

Comment: This is an exceptionally unhelpful answer. It doesn't have anywhere near enough information for someone to actually implement the algorithm you sketch.

Comment: His answer is very good but you're right @NickBailey - not enough detail. I implemented this in another thread (but I did not see this thread until now) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127704/algorithm-to-return-all-combinations-of-k-elements-from-n/42190945#42190945

Comment: I believe it is this one is by far the better answer.

int n = 3;
std::string s = "ABCDEFGH";
std::vector<int> mask = {0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1};
std::set<std::string> sets;
do {
  sets.insert(calculate_set(mask, s));
} while(std::next_permutation(mask.begin(),mask.end()));

where calculate_set behave like this:

ABCDEFGH
01010010

-> return BDG

Answer (score 2):

This is python. Sorry for the spanish ;)

```
from pprint import pprint
conjunto = [1,2,3,4, 5,6,7,8,9,10]
k = 3
lista = []
iteraciones = [0]
def subconjuntos(l, k):
    if k == len(l):
        if not l in lista:
            lista.append(l)
        return
    for i in l:
        aux = l[:]
        aux.remove(i)
        result = subconjuntos(aux, k)
        iteraciones[0] += 1
        if not result in lista and result:
            lista.append( result)

subconjuntos(conjunto, k)
print (lista)
print ('cant iteraciones: ' + str(iteraciones[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out my solution

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;


 public class Subset_K {
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Set<String> x;
    int n=4;
    int k=2;
    int arr[]={1,2,3,4};
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=1;i<=(n-k);i++)
        sb.append("0");
    for(int i=1;i<=k;i++)
        sb.append("1");
    String bin=sb.toString();
    x=generatePerm(bin);
    Set<ArrayList <Integer>> outer=new HashSet<ArrayList <Integer>>();
    for(String s:x){
        int dec=Integer.parseInt(s,2);
        ArrayList<Integer> inner=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if((dec&(1<<j))>0)
                inner.add(arr[j]);
        }
        outer.add(inner);
    }
    for(ArrayList<?> z:outer){
        System.out.println(z);
    }
}

    public static Set<String> generatePerm(String input)
{
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    if (input == "")
        return set;

    Character a = input.charAt(0);

    if (input.length() > 1)
    {
        input = input.substring(1);

        Set<String> permSet = generatePerm(input);

        for (String x : permSet)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= x.length(); i++)
            {
                set.add(x.substring(0, i) + a + x.substring(i));
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        set.add(a + "");
    }
    return set;
}
}
```

I am working on a 4 element set for test purpose and using k=2. What I try to do is initially generate a binary string where k bits are set and n-k bits are not set. Now using this string I find all the possible permutations of this string. And then using these permutations I output the respective element in the set. Would be great if someone could tell me about the complexity of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
   #include<iostream>
   #include<cstdio>
   #include<vector>
   using namespace std;
   vector<int> v;
   vector<vector<int> > result;

  void subset(int arr[],int k,int n,int idx){
  if(idx==n)
 return;

if(k==1){
    for(int i=idx;i<n;i++)
     {
        v.push_back(arr[i]);
        result.push_back(v);
        v.pop_back();
     }
}

 for(int j=idx;j<n;j++) {
  v.push_back(arr[j]);
  subset(arr,k-1,n,j+1);
  v.pop_back();
  }
 }

int main(){
int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int k = 4;
int n =sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
subset(arr,k,n,0);

for(int i = 0;i<result.size();i++)
 { 
  for(int j = 0;j<result[i].size();j++)
   {
     cout << result[i][j] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another intresting solution.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
long factorial(int n) { return (n==1|| n==0|| n < 0) ? 1 : n *factorial(n-1) ;}
void printS(int set[],int n,int k) 
{ 

   long noofsubset =  factorial(n) / (factorial(n-k)*factorial(k));
   bitset<32> z ((1 << (k)) - 1);
   string s = z.to_string();
    int i = 0;
        while(i<noofsubset)
        { 
                  for (int j = 0; j  < n;j++)
                  {
                      if(s[(32-n)+j] == '1')
                        cout << set[j]<<" ";
                  }
                    cout << endl;
                next_permutation(s.begin(),s.end());
                i++;
        } 
}

void printSubsetsOfArray(int input[], int size) {
    int k  = 3;
  printS(input,size,k)  ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Slight improvement for @amit top voted answer:

His code keep checking combinations even when there won't be any chance for them to reach the wanted length. We can stop creating combinations much earlier:

e.g. for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] , length = 8 , the code will still try all combinations of length 7,6,5,4,3,2,1 although they will obviously just be thrown away, halting only when idx reaches the end of the list.

We can improve the running time by stopping earlier, when we already know the set we build + the optional remaining digits will still be too short.

change :

```
//unsuccessful stop clause
if (idx == superSet.size()) return;
```

into:

```
// unsuccessful stop clause
Integer maxFutureElements = superSet.size() - idx;
if (current.size() + maxFutureElements < length) return;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple algorithm to enumerate all k-subsets of [n]={0,...,n-1} in lexicographic order. That is, the first of these subsets is S0=(0,1,2...,k-1), and the last is Slast=(n-k, n-k+1,...,n-1). For any k-subset S and for any 0 < j < k, we have S[j-1] < S[j] <= n+j-k.

For example, if n=10 and k=4, S0=(0,1,2,3) and Slast=(6,7,8,9). Notice, for example, that no combination can have S[1]>7 (in which case we'd have S[j]>n+j-k), since then there would be not enough values left to fill thr remaining positions j=2..3.

The idea of the algorithm is to start with the first combination S0, and then call next() repeatedly to generate the next k-subset each time. The function next() traverses the current k-subset backwards, starting from the last position j=k-1 down to 0, until it finds an entry S[j] that has not yet reached its maximum allowed value n+j-k and can thus be increased. Then it increases this position by one and fills the remaining positions, j+1..k-1 with consecutive values from S[j]+1. The algorithm stops as soon as no position can be further increased.

For example, suppose we have S=(3,7,8,9). Starting from j=3, we see that S[3],S[2],S[1] have reached their maximum values. Thus, the rightmost position that can still be increased is S[0]. This value is updated to S[0]+1=4, and the following positions are updated to 5,6,7. Hence the next k-subset will be S=(4,5,6,7).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>


bool next(int *S, int k, int n) {
    int j = k-1;
    while (j >= 0 && S[j] == n + j - k) 
        j--;
    if (j < 0) return false;
    S[j] += 1;
    for (int i = j+1; i < k ; i++) 
        S[i] = S[i-1] + 1;
    return true;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int n = 10;
    int k = 4;
    int *S = (int *)calloc(k, sizeof(int));
    for (int j = 0; j < k; S[++j] = j); //first k-subset
    int no = 0;
    do {
        printf("subset #%d: ",no++);
        for (int j=0; j < k; j++) {
            printf("%d ", S[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } while(next(S, k, n));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check my solution:-

```
private static void printPermutations(List<Integer> list, int subSetSize) {
    List<Integer> prefixList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    printPermutations(prefixList, list, subSetSize);
}

private static void printPermutations(List<Integer> prefixList, List<Integer> list, int subSetSize) {
    if (prefixList.size() == subSetSize) {
        System.out.println(prefixList);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Integer removed = list.remove(i);
            prefixList.add(removed);
            printPermutations(prefixList, list, subSetSize);
            prefixList.remove(removed);
            list.add(i, removed);
        }
    }
}
```

This is similar to String permutations:-

```
private static void printPermutations(String str) {
    printAllPermutations("", str);
}

private static void printAllPermutations(String prefix, String restOfTheString) {
    int len = restOfTheString.length();
    System.out.println(prefix);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printAllPermutations(prefix + restOfTheString.charAt(i), restOfTheString.substring(0, i) + restOfTheString.substring(i + 1, len));
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice if you added some explanation about what you did and why

Comment: @UriAgassi are you able to follow the solution now?

Comment: A verbal explanation is a lot better than more code... You took the time to answer an old question - give us an insight on how your answer is better than the rest.

Answer (score 0):

This is an implemation in F#:

```
// allSubsets: int -> int -> Set<Set<int>>
let rec allSubsets n k =
    match n, k with
    | _, 0 -> Set.empty.Add(Set.empty)
    | 0, _ -> Set.empty
    | n, k -> Set.union (Set.map (fun s -> Set.add n s) (allSubsets (n-1) (k-1)))
                        (allSubsets (n-1) k)
```

You can try it in the F# REPL:

```
> allSubsets 3 2;;

val it : Set<Set<int>> = set [set [1; 2]; set [1; 3]; set [2; 3]]

> allSubsets 4 2;;

val it : Set<Set<int>> = set [set [1; 2]; set [1; 3]; set [1; 4]; set [2; 3]; set [2; 4]; set [3; 4]]
```

This Java class implements the same algorithm:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class AllSubsets {

    public static Set<Set<Integer>> allSubsets(int setSize, int subsetSize) {
        if (subsetSize == 0) {
            HashSet<Set<Integer>> result = new HashSet<>();
            result.add(new HashSet<>());
            return result;
        }
        if (setSize == 0) {
            return new HashSet<>();
        }
        Set<Set<Integer>> sets1 = allSubsets((setSize - 1), (subsetSize - 1));
        for (Set<Integer> set : sets1) {
            set.add(setSize);
        }
        Set<Set<Integer>> sets2 = allSubsets((setSize - 1), subsetSize);
        sets1.addAll(sets2);
        return sets1;
    }
}
```

If you do not like F# or Java then visit this website. It lists solutions to your particular problem in various programming languages:

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript implementation:

```
var subsetArray = (function() {
  return {
    getResult: getResult
  }

  function getResult(array, n) {

    function isBigEnough(value) {
      return value.length === n;
    }

    var ps = [
      []
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0, len = ps.length; j < len; j++) {
        ps.push(ps[j].concat(array[i]));
      }
    }
    return ps.filter(isBigEnough);
  }
})();



 var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9];
 console.log(subsetArray.getResult(arr,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iterative version in python. Essence of it is increment_counters() function which returns all possible combinations. We know it needs to be called C(n,r) times.

```
def nchooser(n,r):
    """Calculate the n choose r manual way"""
    import math
    f = math.factorial
    return f(n) / f(n-r) / f(r)

def increment_counters(rc,r,n):
    """This is the essense of the algorithm. It generates all possible indexes.
    Ex: for n = 4, r = 2, rc will have values (0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,3).
    You may have better understanding if you print all possible 35 values for
    n = 7, r = 3."""

    rc[r-1] += 1     # first increment the least significant counter
    if rc[r-1] < n:  # if it does not overflow, return
        return

    # overflow at the last counter may cause some of previous counters to overflow
    # find where it stops (ex: in n=7,r=3 case, 1,2,3 will follow 0,5,6)
    for i in range(r-2,-1,-1): # from r-2 to 0 inclusive
        if rc[i] < i+n-r:
            break
    # we found that rc[i] will not overflow. So, increment it and reset the
    # counters right to it. 
    rc[i] += 1
    for j in range(i+1,r):
        rc[j] = rc[j-1] + 1

def combinations(lst, r):
    """Return all different sub-lists of size r"""
    n = len(lst)
    rc = [ i for i in range(r) ]  # initialize counters
    res = []
    for i in range(nchooser(n,r)): # increment the counters max possible times 
        res.append(tuple(map(lambda k: lst[k],rc)))
        increment_counters(rc,r,n)

    return res
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Java version of what I think Simple is talking about, using a binary representation of all sets in the power set. It's similar to how Abhiroop Sarkar did it, but I think a boolean array makes more sense than a string when you are just representing binary values.

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> getSubsets(int m, Object[] objects){
    // m = size of subset, objects = superset of objects
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> pot = new ArrayList<>();
    int n = objects.length;
    int p = 1;
    if(m==0)
        return subsets;
    for(int i=0; i<=n; i++){
        pot.add(p);
        p*=2;
    }
    for(int i=1; i<p; i++){
        boolean[] binArray = new boolean[n];
        Arrays.fill(binArray, false);
        int y = i;
        int sum = 0;
        for(int j = n-1; j>=0; j--){
            int currentPot = pot.get(j);
            if(y >= currentPot){
                binArray[j] = true;
                y -= currentPot;
                sum++;
            }
            if(y<=0)
                break;
        }
        if(sum==m){
            ArrayList<Object> subsubset = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j=0; j < n; j++){
                if(binArray[j]){
                    subsubset.add(objects[j]);
                }
            }
            subsets.add(subsubset);
        }
    }

    return subsets;
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this, but it returns wrong results and becomes extremely slow for larger arrays. I have an alternate solution here that is correct, fast and provides an iterator instead of a list (saves memory): http://code.botcompany.de/1027914 (click on "Pure Java version")

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for Iterator pattern answer then here you go.

```
public static <T> Iterable<List<T>> getList(final Iterable<? extends T> list) {

    List<List<T>> listOfList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (T t: list)
        listOfList.add(Collections.singletonList(t));

    return listOfList;
}
public static <T> Iterable<List<T>> getIterable(final Iterable<? extends T> list, final int size) {

    final List<T> vals = new ArrayList<>();
    int numElements = 0;
    for (T t : list) {
        vals.add(t);
        numElements++;
    }

    if (size == 1) {
        return getList(vals);
    }
    if (size == numElements) {
        return Collections.singletonList(vals);
    }

    return new Iterable<List<T>>() {

        @Override
        public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
            return new Iterator<List<T>>() {

                int currPos = 0;                    
                Iterator<List<T>> nextIterator = getIterable(
                    vals.subList(this.currPos + 1, vals.size()), size - 1).iterator();

                @Override
                public boolean hasNext() {
                    if ((this.currPos < vals.size()-2) && (this.currPos+size < vals.size()))
                        return true;
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public List<T> next() {
                    if (!nextIterator.hasNext()) {
                        this.currPos++;
                        nextIterator = getIterable(vals.subList(this.currPos+1, vals.size()), size-1).iterator();
                    }
                    final List<T> ret = new ArrayList<>(nextIterator.next());
                    ret.add(0, vals.get(this.currPos));
                    return ret;
                }
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short python algorithm. I haven't used any predefined functions as such so I believe it could be easily translated to Java/C

```
def subs(l,n):

if(len(l)<k):

return []

elif(k==0):

return [[]]

else:

lis=[[l[0]]+b for b in (subs(l[1:],k-1))]

return (lis+subs(l[1:],k))
```

Here l is the list [1,2,...,m]

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

void findAllSubsetOfSizeK(int ind, vector<int> &arr, vector<int> temp, int k, set<vector<int>> &st)
{

    if (temp.size() == k)
    {
        st.insert(temp);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = ind; i < arr.size(); i++)
    {
        temp.push_back(arr[i]);
        findAllSubsetOfSizeK(i + 1, arr, temp, k, st);
        temp.pop_back();
    }
}

vector<vector<int>> solve(int n, int k)
{

    vector<int> arr(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = i + 1;
    }

    set<vector<int>> st;
    findAllSubsetOfSizeK(0, arr, {}, k, st);
    vector<vector<int>> res;
    for (auto i : st)
    {
        res.push_back(i);
    }
    return res;
}

int main()
{

    int n, k;

    cin >> n >> k;

    vector<vector<int>> res = solve(n, k);

    for (auto i : res)
    {

        for (auto j : i)
        {

            cout << j << " ";
        }

        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```