# Every (specific sized) combination from set/array with no duplicate items

Tags: php, arrays, combinations, permutation

Let's say I have
    set = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

I'd like the following in return
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    [4, 3, 2, 1, 6]
    [7, 5, 1, 3, 2]..........

Essentially, as the title states I'm looking to generate specific sized combinations from an array but each combination can't have any duplicate items (so no aaab, aaac if you get the idea).

I've found another question here as well, but it had dupes within the combinations. I've tried tweaking and writing the recursive function to no avail :/

Comment: Could you please post some of your (relevant) code?

Comment: $set = array('A', 'B', 'C', D', 'E', 'F', 'G');
Just need combinations like ['A', 'B', 'C'] ['C', 'D', 'G'] etc..

Comment: Can you post the code you've found...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067556/php-algorithm-to-generate-all-combinations-of-a-specific-size-from-a-single-set

Comment: Really, it's just generating all combinations of size x for a set of elements of size y with no dupes.

Comment: I understand, but I think this function does not make any duplicates...I just tested it ... Can you give me an inputs which you are using when getting duplicates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright - all possible subsets without duplicates and assuming that the order does not matter, i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` is the same as `[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]`. Minimalistic example:

```
<?php
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7);

function getSubsets($set, $items) {
  $result = array();
  getSubsets2($set, $items, 0, array(), $result);
  return $result;
}

function getSubsets2($set, $items, $index, $current, &$result) {
  if (sizeof($current) === $items) {
    $result[] = $current;
    return;
  }
  if ($index < sizeof($set)) {
    getSubsets2($set, $items, $index + 1, $current, $result);
    $current[] = $set[$index];
    getSubsets2($set, $items, $index + 1, $current, $result);
  }
}

$subsets = getSubsets($arr, 5);

echo(sizeof($subsets)); // 21
?>
```

Not to carry off someone else's laurels: This is 100% based on [another Stack Overflow answer written in java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12548381/4616087).

Comment: I'm not looking for random per say. I'm looking for every, each and every possible 5 item combinations from that set of 7 (my example). Edit: I revised my question and title accordingly!

Comment: Beauty. You're a gem.