# Find unique permutations from array of words, limiting a set of words by 12 characters

Tags: php, permutation

Let me explain, i need this to develop a unique title generator based on a set of words pre defined.

For example, i have this list of words:

> $list = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear'];

I have a limited size of the title, for example: 1 characters
If i generate a list of all permutation, i will have:

```
apple
banana
pear
apple banana
apple pear
apple banana pear
banana apple
banana pear
banana apple pear
pear apple
pear banana
pear banana apple
```

But i don't want this, ny rules are: Words cannot repeat again in another set of words and i want only the biggest set of words <= 12 characteres

The result would be:

```
apple banana
apple pear
banana pear
```

I already tried following solutions but none of these help:

> [PHP algorithm to generate all combinations of a specific size from a single set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19067556/php-algorithm-to-generate-all-combinations-of-a-specific-size-from-a-single-set)

> [PHP Find All (somewhat) Unique Combinations of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310553/php-find-all-somewhat-unique-combinations-of-an-array?rq=1)

> [Every (specific sized) combination from set/array with no duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801262/every-specific-sized-combination-from-set-array-with-no-duplicate-items?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> [Efficient PHP algorithm to generate all combinations / permutations of inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36612560/efficient-php-algorithm-to-generate-all-combinations-permutations-of-inputs?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> [How do you generate a list of all possible strings given a generator of characters and a length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53836020/how-do-you-generate-a-list-of-all-possible-strings-given-a-generator-of-characte?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have this code, but it is not removing duplicates as i want

```
public static function search_get_combos($array = array(), $maxCaracters=12) {

        sort($array);

        $terms = array();

        for ($dec = 1; $dec < pow(2, count($array)); $dec++) {
            $curterm = array();
            foreach (str_split(strrev(decbin($dec))) as $i => $bit) {
                if ($bit) {
                    $curterm[] = $array[$i];
                }
            }
            if (!in_array($curterm, $terms) && count($curterm) > 1) {
                $title = implode(' ', $curterm);
                if (strlen($title) <= $maxCaracters){
                    $terms[$title] = $curterm;
                }
            }
        }

        return $terms;

    }
```

Output:

```
array(6) {
  ["Apple"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
  }
  ["Banana"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Banana"
  }
  ["Apple Banana"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "Banana"
  }
  ["Pear"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Pear"
  }
  ["Apple Pear"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(5) "Apple"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Pear"
  }
  ["Banana Pear"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Banana"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "Pear"
  }
}
```

Comment: You're stating "i want only the biggest set of words <= 10 characteres" and then you provide "apple banana" as one of the expected results. Did you mean 12 like in your title?

Comment: yes, said wrong^^

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```php
<?php

$list = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'a'];

$result = [];

foreach($list as $k => $v) {
    unset($list[$k]);
    foreach($list as $subv) {
        $word_combination = $v.' '.$subv;
        if (strlen($word_combination) >= 10) {
            array_push($result, $v.' '.$subv);
        }
    }
}

print_r($result);
print(implode(' ', $result));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple banana
    [1] => apple pear
    [2] => banana pear
)
apple banana apple pear banana pear
```

And I don't understand about

> i want only the biggest set of words <= 10 characteres

Do you mean `apple banana` must be more than 10 characters (`apple banana` = 12 chars)?
If yes, I added check for this. For example `apple a` (7 chars) will be ignored.

Comment: For example, i generate this list:

Apple banana pear
Apple banana
apple
banana

Apple banana pear > 10 characters, remove it
Apple banana < 10 characters keep it
apple reapeat in Apple banana, remove it
banana repeat in apple banana, remove it

Comment: "Apple banana < 10 characters". But Apple banana is 12 characters (or 11 without space). Do you mean 1 word == 1 character?

Comment: sorry, I said wrong, it's not 10 characters, it's 12 characters.
I'll try to explain it another way:
let's assume that the generated titles will be:
Women's Shoes
Women's Shoes

As the women's pumps shoe is repeated in the previous title, this must be removed.

What I need in the end, is that it manages all possible combinations of titles keeping only the largest titles under 60 characters, any other title combination where all words are within a larger title must be removed from the list, end only the biggest titles that are under 60 characters.

Comment: @DilneiSoetheSpancerski Ok. you can change `strlen($word_combination) >= 10` to `strlen($word_combination) >= 12` in my solution and only combinations longer than 12 symbols will be shown. At least my output same as your question's `The result would be:`