# How to work with mutable lists in F#?

Tags: list, f#, mutable

I'm new to F# and I'm making a program that requires finding every sub-list of given length of some list. I wasn't sure how to go about this so I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548312/find-all-subsets-of-length-k-in-an-array) and decided to port the answer to F#. Here's what I have:

```
let rec getSubLists (len : int) (list : List<int>) : List<List<int>> =
  let result = new List<List<int>>()
  let current = new List<int>()

  let rec findSubLists (len : int) (superSet : List<int>) (current : List<int>) (soln : List<List<int>>) (idx : int) : unit =
    if current.Length = len then soln.Insert(len - 1, current)
    elif idx = superSet.Length then
      let x = superSet.[idx] 
      current.Insert(len, x)
      findSubLists len superSet current soln (idx + 1)
      current.RemoveAt(x)
      findSubLists len superSet current soln (idx + 1)
    else ()

  findSubLists len list current result 0
  result
```

The compiler is upset about a few things: it says there is no constructor for `List<int>`, `List<List<int>>`, and it says that `Insert` and `RemoveAt` are not defined. I found these methods in the [microsoft docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1). [This tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fsharp/fsharp_mutable_lists.htm) mentions `RemoveAt`, but it uses `Add` instead of `Insert`, which also didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In F# the type `List<'t>` is the immutable F# list. It is not the same as `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`, which is what is described in the docs you linked.

To access the latter, either open the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace (but beware: this will shadow the regular F# list) or refer to it by its F# alias, `ResizeArray<'t>`, which also better expresses its true nature.

```
let rec getSubLists (len : int) (list : ResizeArray<int>) : ResizeArray<ResizeArray<int>> =
  let result = new ResizeArray<ResizeArray<int>>()
  let current = new ResizeArray<int>()

  let rec findSubLists (len : int) (superSet : ResizeArray<int>) (current : ResizeArray<int>) (soln : ResizeArray<ResizeArray<int>>) (idx : int) : unit =
    if current.Count = len then soln.Insert(len - 1, current)
    elif idx = superSet.Count then
      let x = superSet.[idx] 
      current.Insert(len, x)
      findSubLists len superSet current soln (idx + 1)
      current.RemoveAt(x)
      findSubLists len superSet current soln (idx + 1)
    else ()

  findSubLists len list current result 0
  result
```

(also note that it's `Count`, not `Length`)