# Is there a method returns all possible combinations for n choose k?

Tags: java, math, combinations

I'm looking for library function which returns any combination of n subset from the k set. For example I have a set {1,2,3,4,5} and I need any combination of 3 numbers included in this set. Order doesn't matter.
So this function should returns:

> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2,
>   3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]

I have tried to write it by myself, but unsuccesfully and I give up. It works only when I take 3 numbers from any set.
Maybe someone knows library function for this issue.

Comment: I think this is achievable by for-loops. Need some time to formulate though...

Comment: Not the finest example IMO, but http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Combinations#Java has something.

Comment: One very simple way - possibly not the most efficient, but easy to understand - would be with a combination of `Arrays.asList`, `Collections.shuffle` and `List.subList`.

Comment: İf you need count of all subset you can use combination 
 http://www.mathwords.com/c/combination_formula.htm

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12548312

Comment: A search for "java combination generator" turns up several possibilities.

Comment: I found recursive solution, but it only prints out combinations. I tried to modify it to return all combinations as an array. But it doesn't work. I paste my code here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54246224/10929764

Answer (score 0):

I do not know any library functions by heart but you could use the following solution:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.*;

public class CombinationCalc<T> {
    private void getSubsets(List<T> input, int length, int index, Set<T> currentSet, List<Set<T>> solution) {
        if (currentSet.size() == length) {
            solution.add(new HashSet<>(currentSet));
            return;
        }
        if (index == input.size()) {
            return;
        }
        T x = input.get(index);
        currentSet.add(x);
        getSubsets(input, length, index + 1, currentSet, solution);
        currentSet.remove(x);
        getSubsets(input, length, index + 1, currentSet, solution);
    }

    public List<Set<T>> getSubsets(List<T> input, int length) {
        List<Set<T>> solution = new ArrayList<>();
        getSubsets(input, length, 0, new HashSet<>(), solution);
        return solution;
    }

    public void printSolution(List<Set<T>> solution, PrintStream ps) {
        Iterator<Set<T>> solutionIterator = solution.iterator();
        ps.print("[");
        if (!solutionIterator.hasNext()) {
            ps.print("]");
        }
        while (solutionIterator.hasNext()) {
            Set<T> solutionEntry = solutionIterator.next();
            Iterator<T> setEntry = solutionEntry.iterator();
            ps.print("[");
            if (!setEntry.hasNext()) {
                ps.print("]");
            }
            while (setEntry.hasNext()) {
                T entry = setEntry.next();
                ps.print(entry);
                if (setEntry.hasNext()) {
                    ps.print(", ");
                } else {
                    ps.print("]");
                }
            }
            if (solutionIterator.hasNext()) {
                ps.print(", ");
            } else {
                ps.print("]");
            }
        }
        ps.println();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CombinationCalc<Integer> calc = new CombinationCalc<>();
        List<Integer> input = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
        List<Set<Integer>> solution = calc.getSubsets(input, 3);

        calc.printSolution(solution, System.out);
    }
}
```

It's based on [amit's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572670/amit) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12548312/find-all-subsets-of-length-k-in-an-array).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple and short solution using streams:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toSet;

public class MakeSubsets {
  static <T> Set<Set<T>> subsets(Set<T> set, int size) {
    if (size < 1) {
      return Collections.singleton(Collections.emptySet());
    }
    return set.stream()
          .flatMap(e -> subsets(remove(set, e), size - 1).stream().map(s -> add(s, e)))
          .collect(toSet());
  }

  static <T> Set<T> add(Set<T> set, T elem) {
    Set<T> newSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(set);
    newSet.add(elem);
    return newSet;
  }

  static <T> Set<T> remove(Set<T> set, T elem) {
    Set<T> newSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(set);
    newSet.remove(elem);
    return newSet;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
    System.out.println(subsets(set, 3));
  }
}
```

How it works: The method `subsets` produces the set of all subsets of given size.

In case of  `size < 1` it returns a set, containing only the empty set.

Otherwise for each element of the given set, it produces a new set without this selected element. Then it produces (recursively) the set of the subsets with `size - 1` elements of this smaller set. It then adds the selected element to each set in the result. Therefore all sets in the result have the desired size.

The recursion terminates because in each recursion level the `size` will decrease by one, which will evenually be `< 1`.

The assumption here is that `set.size() >= size` and `size >= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

I found here recursive solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16256122/10929764
but it only prints out combinations. I tried to modify it to return all combinations as an ArrayList, but it doesn't work.
Here is code:

```
public ArrayList<String[]> comb2(ArrayList<String>arr, int len, int startPosition, String[] result, ArrayList<String[]> allResults){
    if (len == 0){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
        allResults.add(result);
        return allResults;
    }
    for (int i = startPosition; i <= arr.size()-len; i++){
        result[result.length - len] = arr.get(i);
        comb2(arr, len-1, i+1, result,allResults);
    }
    return allResults;
}
```

It prints out properly all combinations:

> [A, B, C] [A, B, D] [A, B, E] [A, C, D] [A, C, E] [A, D, E] [B, C, D]
>   [B, C, E] [B, D, E] [C, D, E]

but when I print out allResults which was previously returned by comb2 method than I get:

> [C, D, E] [C, D, E] [C, D, E] [C, D, E] [C, D, E] [C, D, E] [C, D, E]
>   [C, D, E] [C, D, E] [C, D, E]

Comment: User Ricola help me to fix it in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54250805/10929764